# Double precision CUDA code being faster than single precision counterpart for a fixed data size

Tags: c++, performance, cuda

I have implemented an algorithm in CUDA and seems it's running faster with double precision than with single precision.

I know that usually single precision is faster in GPU. My GPU is Nvidia Geforce GT 650M.

The algorithm pseudo code is the following:

```
for k to numIterations
    for j to numRowsOfAMatrix
        CUDAmemset(double arrayGPU)
        CUBLASdotproduct(double arrayGPU,double arrayGPU) [using cublasDdot]
        CUBLASdotproduct(double arrayGPU,double arrayGPU) [using cublasDdot]
        CUBLASscalarVectorMultiplication(scalarCPU,double arrayGPU) [using cublasDaxpy]
        CUBLASvectorSum(double arrayGPU,double arrayGPU) [using cublasDaxpy]
    end
end
```

I've run some tests with the following properties: Arrays are 2500 length. Matrix row lenght is 2700.

The times that I'm obtaining are the following:

**50 iterations:**

20.9960 seconds for single

20.1881 seconds for double

**200 iterations:**

81.9562 seconds for single

78.9490 seconds for double

**500 iterations:**

199.661 seconds for single

199.045 seconds for double

**1000 iterations:**

413.129 seconds for single

396.205 seconds for double

Any idea why double precision is faster?

Comment: Are you sure that the difference between 20.996 and 20.1881 is statistically significant? Your actual question might well be "Why does single precision and double precision versions of this code take the same time to execute?" and the answer to that might be "because API latency and memory transfer overhead dominate the wallclock time". But we need more information to answer this, I think.

Comment: @talonmies I have added more bench results with different iterations. I believe with 1000 iterations the times are already significant?(though that 500 iterations results are again close) Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't say so. How large are the arrays? And what platform are you running this on.

Comment: @talonmies Arrays are 2500 length. Matrix row size is 2700.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe you can say that the double precision version is faster than the single precision version. Your own timing shows both take about 20 seconds for 50 iterations and about 200 seconds for 500 iterations. The question then becomes why?

To me it just looks like your code is dominated by API and PCI-e bus latency. Even the two times memory bandwidth difference between single and double precision is probably irrelevant in this case. If each array is only about 2500 long, then the arithmetic and device memory transaction portions of the calculation will be absolutely tiny compared to the overall execution time.

Looking at your pseudocode shows why. At each iteration, the two dot calls have launch one or more kernels, wait for them to finish, then download a scalar result from the device. Then scalars have to be uploaded to the device for each axpy call followed by a kernel launch. From the information in comments, this means you code performs perhaps two blocking memory copies and six kernel launches per input row, and there are 2700 input rows per iteration. That means you code is performing *10-15 thousand* GPU API calls per iteration, which is a lot of transactions and API latency (especially if you are doing this on a WDDM Windows platform) for a nothing more than a few thousand FLOPs and a few tens of kb of GPU memory access per row.

The fact that your GPU has 12 times higher peak single precision than double precision arithmetic throughput is irrelevant in this case, because the computation time is a vanishingly small fraction of the total wall clock time you measure.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Seems the real problem here is the transfers between cpu <-> gpu taking more time than computation. Just one question is it really a large (in terms of time) transfer problem only transferring one integer (scalar) between the device <-> host? Shouldn't it be really fast (since it's only one number)? P.S. I'm using WDDM Windows platform.

Comment: @RandomGuy: No, I don't think you have understood. It isn't the transfer time, or the computation time that is the problem here. It is *latency*. Ever CUDA API call which does something on the GPU has a fixed time cost. Your code is running probably running 10000 different API calls which require an operation on the GPU per iteration. The fact that each operation takes almost zero time to finish becomes irrelevant - it is the fixed time cost which is determined how long the code takes to run. This is why double and single precision take the same time.

Comment: Thanks I was not understanding that it was the latency (fixed time) problem. Indeed you are right I'm doing thousands of GPU calls per k th iteration. :)

Answer (score 0):

The difference in computational cost between two algorithms (in your case, the single and double precision versions) is generally measured by the *asymptotic computational complexity*. It is not surprising that double precision can have the same performance as single precision for a fixed (small, in your case) vector length, for the reasons explained by talonmies (latency). To really state which algorithm is faster, you should analyze the timing against the vector length `N`, starting from small to large values of `N`.

Another example, which however has nothing to do with GPGPU, is FFT, which has an asymptotic complexity of `O(NlogN)` and then is more convenient than "brute-force" summation of DFT, which as `O(N^2)` complexity. But, if you compare the timing between FFT and "brute-force" DFT summation for very low values of `N`, you will find that "brute-force" DFT summation will take the least time.